# sessionのキーの取得は可能ですか？

Tags: php, cakephp

cakephp3にて、セッションを設定し、キーを与えているのですが、そのキーを取得することは可能ですか？

```
$this->Session->write('add',
                [
                    'userid' => $request['userid'],
                    'username' => $request['username'],
                    'password' => $request['password'],
                    'mailaddress' => $request['mailaddress'],
                    'regdate'=> $date
            ]);
```

上記の'add'を取得して、その値により処理を変更したいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純にキーの有無を調べたいのであれば、 `Session::check($key)` を使用します。

Controller上であれば、以下のようにして分岐します。

```
if ($this->request->getSession()->check('add')) {
    // 'add' が存在する場合の処理
}
```

Session::check($key)
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/development/sessions.html#Session::check

(CakePHP <= 3.4 であれば、 `$this->request->getSession()` の代わりに `$this->request->session()` としてください。

---

また、`Session::read()` にて、セッションに記録されている全ての内容を取得できます。

Controller上で、Sessionのキーリストを取得するのであれば、以下のようにします。

```
$sessionKeys = array_keys($this->request->getSession()->read());
```

Session::read($key)
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/development/sessions.html#Session::read